# .NET MAUI - Datatrigger/behaviours for changing image control based on user click

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Developing a bottomsheet, in the bottomsheet i have a listview, where the listview contains image and label control. Image should be visible only if the user taps on the label to control the image visibility changes.

Expected is something like below:

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5s7J.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5s7J.png)]

Below is the XAML code.

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell >
                 <Grid>
                     <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                         <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding GestureCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                     </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                     <Image x:Name="SheetImage" Grid.Column="0" Source="arrow_downward.png" Margin="10" IsVisible="{Binding IconVisible}"/>
                     <Image x:Name="SheetImage1" Grid.Column="0" Source="arrow_upward.png" Margin="10" IsVisible="{Binding IconSortVisible}">
                         <Image.Triggers>
                             <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference SheetImage}, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
                                 <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"/>
                             </DataTrigger>
                         </Image.Triggers>
                     </Image>

                     <mdc:Label Text="{Binding MenuTitle}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="30" >
                         <mdc:Label.Triggers>
                             <DataTrigger TargetType="mdc:Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference SheetImage}, Path=IsVisible}" Value="False">
                                 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="44" />
                             </DataTrigger>
                             <!--<DataTrigger TargetType="mdc:Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference SheetImage1}, Path=IsVisible}" Value="False">
                                 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="44" />
                             </DataTrigger>-->
                         </mdc:Label.Triggers>
                     </mdc:Label>
                 </Grid>
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

I need to know how best we can handle this. The code i have written in the backend seems to be messy and written lot of boolean properties to get this happened.

Any suggestions to handle this on a best way.

Comment: Why don't you just rotate the image?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about what effect you want to achieve? Do you mean when pressing on the label the arrow is down, and when releasing the arrow is up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to go with ViewModel per each menu item. You can set there ImageSource bindable property which can be updated on tap command.

```csharp
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    // You can set here your images as constants or 
    // create properties to provide image source during object initialization
    private const string DotNetBotImage = "dotnet_bot.png";
    private const string MapFillImage = "map_fill.svg";

    public ItemViewModel()
    {
        ItemTapCommand = new Command(ItemTap);
    }

    private string _itemImage = DotNetBotImage;

    public string ItemImage
    {
        get => _itemImage;
        set
        {
            _itemImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _itemLabel = string.Empty;

    public string ItemLabel
    {
        get => _itemLabel;
        set
        {
            _itemLabel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand ItemTapCommand { get; private set; }

    // Update image on tap
    private void ItemTap()
    {
        if (ItemImage == DotNetBotImage)
        {
            ItemImage = MapFillImage;
        }
        else
        {
            ItemImage = DotNetBotImage;
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

After that feel free to create ObservableCollection for ListView:

```csharp
public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>
{
    new ItemViewModel
    {
        ItemLabel = "Test1"
    },
    new ItemViewModel
    {
        ItemLabel = "Test2"
    },
    new ItemViewModel
    {
        ItemLabel = "Test3"
    }
};
```

And here is the markup with the ListView (don't forget to set BindingContext to get access to ObservableCollection).

```xaml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:ItemViewModel">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ItemTapCommand}"/>
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ItemImage}" Margin="10"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemLabel}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="30"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```